# Printing null value from Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add `null` to the `ArrayList` where as it is integer type. But i am getting `NullPointerException`.

Adding `null` to the `ArrayList` is a success, but while printing it exception is being raised.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

public enum Car {
     lamborghini(123),tata(2),audi(50),fiat(15),honda(12);
       private int price;
       Car(int p) {
          price = p;
       }
       int getPrice() {
          return price;
       } 
    }



import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
       public static void main(String args[]){
          System.out.println("All car prices:");
          for (Car c : Car.values())
          System.out.println(c + " costs " 
          + c.getPrice() + " thousand dollars.");

         ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();

         al.add(null);

         for (Car p : Car.values())
             al.add(p.getPrice());

         System.out.println("Size: "+al.size());
      // Loop through elements.
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            **int value = al.get(i);**
            System.out.println("Element: " + value);
        }

        //  switch (c)
       }
    }
```

Comment: You should point out in which exact line you get the `NullPointerException`

Comment: http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2007/09/npe-due-to-autoboxing.html

Comment: Also, you don't show your definition of `al`, `al` does not actually exist in your code.

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList(); is at the line before  al.add(null); Just now i ahve modified the code.

Comment: Is it? Because that line is not there in the code you posted, so the list is null